# SQL query to return default value for a column if no Match in two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create an output table matching two tables. If the second table does not match with the first table then return a default value for a column.

**Example-**

Table 1 -

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Id         |        Name      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        Jon       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        Dan       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |        Mark      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |      Phillips    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          5          |       Watson     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Table 2 -

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Name       |      Result      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Jon        |       Pass       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Phillips     |       Pass       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Watson      |       Fail       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Final Output Table with Join and if data does not match in second table then assign a default value "Fail" to it -

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          Id         |        Name      |      Result      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        Jon       |       Pass       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        Dan       |       Fail       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |        Mark      |       Fail       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4          |      Phillips    |       Pass       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          5          |       Watson     |       Fail       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

How can this be achieved in SQL.

Comment: With a left join of course.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Left join table1 with table2 and use `coalesce` to replace NULL values (when right table has no match) with the default value:

```
select t1.id, 
       t1.name, 
       coalesce(t2.result, 'fail') as Result      
from Table_1 as t1
left outer join Table_2 as t2 on t1.name = t2.name
```

Comment: coalesce was the term I wanted to know... Thanks